# Значення слова "прошу"

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, запозичені-слова

Я помітила, шо на західній Україні слово "прошу" вживають в декількох значеннях:

1. "Будь ласка", "you are welcome";
2. коли перепитують;
3. перепрошую?

Чи варто вживати це слово на іншій частині України?

Чи можна вважати його українським?

Чи це галицизм, запозичення з польскої (пшепрашам) / чеської (prosim) мови ?

Comment: чим відрізняються в запитанні варіанти 2 і 3?

Comment: Чи правильно я розумію: п. 1 — це відповідь на подяку, п. 2 — це коли недочули й перепитують, а п. 3 — це коли просять вибачити за якусь провину?

Answer (score 3):

У статті [В. Васильченко. Мова: Розрізняймо підступних близнюків!](https://uain.press/language/v-yacheslav-vasylchenko-mova-rozriznyajmo-pidstupnyh-blyznyukiv-590550) знаходимо:

> **ПрОшу** – належить до арсеналу етикетних слів, виконує ту ж саму функцію, що й “будь ласка” (будь ласка (синонімічні йому коли (як, якщо) [буде] [твоя, ваша і т. ін.] ласка; з ласки вашої (твоєї і т. ін.) – “чемне звертання при проханні або згоді на що-небудь”).

[Олександр Авраменко](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSjry51GJ0Q) радить вживати **прОшу**, “коли відповідаєте на подяку, якщо ваша послуга була незначною, адже прОшу звучить скромніше, ніж будь ласка”.

У статті [Н. Ф. Баландіна. Перформативи як індикатори функцій конвенційних висловлень](https://movoznavstvo.org.ua/index.php?option=com_attachments&task=download&id=80) знаходимо:

> Сфера функціонування українського 
>   **прошу (просимо)**
>    у значенні **«будь ласка / будь
>   ласкавий / з вашої ласки / коли ваша ласка»** значно вужча.  Іноді таке вживання вважають
>   регіонально  зумовленим.  В  україністиці  існують  спроби  розмежування  функціонального
>   змісту  слова за допомогою  наголосу. 
>   Прошу
>    з  наголосом  на  останньому  складі  рекомен­
>   дується  для  вживання  у  значенні  «прохання»,  «клопотання»,  а  з  наголосом  на  першому
>   складі —  у значенні «будь ласка», «запрошую» 
>   (Гринчишин Д. Г., Капелюшний А.  О.  та ін.
>   Словник труднощів української мови.— K.,  1989.—  С.  257).  Пропонована різнонаголошу-
>   ваність слова 
>   прошу,
>    не маючи під собою чітких об’єктивних критеріїв, не зовсім виправдана
>   й утруднює його вживання. За основу розрізнення пропонують сфери вживання, стилістику, а
>   насправді залучається семантика, принаймні це засвідчують наведені у словнику приклади.

Comment: Ньічого не написано про _прошу_ јак просте вибаченньа — јак _перепрошују_. Недарма ж тут 2 останньі пункти чи останньиј абзац згадује польську та чеську.

Comment: То що вживати коли недочув? На заміну слова прошу.

Comment: @RomanKoroliak, є, наприклад, варіант _[даруйте](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=20914&page=708)_.

Answer (score 1):

З польської це більше відповідник слова "proszę" ( чит. проше),  а не слова "przepraszam" (чит. пшепрашам). Це означає, що його використовують під час прохання і під час відповіді на вдячність. Якщо ви маєте на увазі використання цього слова в ситуації: "Я перепрошую ("пшепрашам" саме це означає), що Ви маєте на увазі кажучи...?", "Я перепрошую, що ви сказали?", то в польській мові в такому випадку сказали б: "słucham?" (чит. слухам).